# use variable to store function in swift as pointer function in Obj-C or C++

Tags: swift, function, class, pointers, variables

I try to create a class variable for later assign it a function, to later call this function just by using the variable.
The idea is to be able to change the function pointed by the variable whe user touch differents buttons, and the call is made in an update loop function
all functions i want assign in the variable is on the code because them contains a animation codes but different, and i don't want to use a switch, is more efficient to call a function as is made in Obj-C or C++ with pointer function

class declaration

```
private var animationFunction: (TimeInterval)
```

error on this line : Class 'MenuScene' has no initializers

try to assign function :

```
/**** interface ****/
func addInterface()
{
    // couleur de fond et taille de la vue de la pub
    self.backgroundColor = Constants.UI.colorsArray[appDelegate.theme][Constants.UI.C_0101100_COLOR_BACKGROUND]

    // animation
    animationFunction = standardAnimation
}
```

on line assignment i get this error : 
Cannot assign value of type '(TimeInterval) -> ()' (aka '(Double) -> ()') to type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

the function i want to assign into class variable

```
func standardAnimation(dtTime: TimeInterval)
{ do something }
```

Regards,
Cedric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the error

> Class 'MenuScene' has no initializers

you have two options: change the declaration of `animationFunction` to make it an `Optional` or create a designated initializer for `MenuScene` where you assign a value to the non-Optional `animationFunction.

To solve the second error of incompatible types, you need to change the declaration of `animationFunction` since currently it's type is `TimeInterval` and not a function type. From the error message it seems you want a function of type `(TimeInterval)->()`, namely one that accepts a single input parameter of type `TimeInterval` and returns `Void`.

To fix both errors, simply modify the declaration of `animationFunction` to make it `Optional` and have the required function type:

```
private var animationFunction: ((TimeInterval)->())?
```

Comment: Hi, thx a lot just change the declaration resolve all issues.